# How to hot merge MariaDb databases from multiple servers into a single one

Tags: mysql, replication, mariadb, galera, master-slave-replication

### Current Configuration

I currently have 3 servers:

- server `australia` with the database `canberra`
- servers `belgium` and `germany` are a galera cluster with the database `bruxelles`.

### Target Configuration

My final goal is to merge both databases into a single galera cluster:

- servers `australia`, `belgium` and `germany` will be a galera cluster with the databases `canberra` and `bruxelles`.

### Constraints and leeways

`australia`, `belgium` and `germany` are public production servers. They all handle read and write queries from various clients 24/7 (`SELECT`, `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`), so I cannot allow **neither downtime nor read-only** for any of them.

`canberra` and `bruxelles` schemas are obviously distinct, so there is **no risk of collision** when merging.

`canberra` and `bruxelles` schemas are stable (no `ALTER`), so **I can copy the schemas from one server to another at any time**, without any need to keep the schemas in sync.

The servers are adressed by clients through DNS aliases :

- `australia` is behind `pacific.example.com`
- `belgium` and `germany` are behind `europe.example.com` (round-robin handled by HAProxy).

It is **easy to add or change DNS aliases** (eg. edit `europe.example.com` to include `australia` in the round-robin, or to exclude `germany`).

I am **not sure that the galera information is relevant** for this particular issue, so any answer working for 2 servers (let's say `australia` and `belgium`) should be easily translatable to my issue.

### Naive approach

My plan was the following:

1. Initiate a replication where `australia` is the master and `belgium` is the slave.
2. Have `pacific.example.com` target `germany` instead of `australia` (no more write on the master, all writes on the slave)
3. Shut down `australia`
4. Overwrite `australia` as a new galera cluster member behind `europe.example.com`.
5. Reboot `belgium` removing slave config
6. Have `pacific.example.com` target the galera cluster.

However, I found myself unable to initiate the replication. Trying to make `belgium` a slave of `australia` results in the destrution of `bruxelles` database.

### Question

How would you do it?

Comment: Before embarking on this, be sure you can handle the long lag time at `COMMIT` -- something like 200ms.  Also some wsrep tuning may be necessary to even let it run with nodes that far apart.  I suggest you set up a small test platform with 3 nodes and experiment with it -- for tuning, timing, transition, etc.